# How to implement Inheritance: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct

Tags: c, oop, inheritance, struct

I have :

`my_entity.h`

```
typedef struct {

    long _id;
    char *_myEntityType;
    char *_myEntitySubType;

    long _myEntityGUID;
    long _myEntityOwnerGUID;
    long _myEntityContainerGUID;

} MyEntity;

typedef struct {

    MyEntity *_myEntity;

} MyContainerEntity;
```

I get the following error when I try running the project:

```
/my_entity.h: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct MyContainerEntity MyContainerEntity’
 } MyContainerEntity;
   ^
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It seems you already have such a type-alias defined for an actual `MyContainerEntity` structure. Try to read the whole error message, it will usually tell you where both the old and the new definitions are.

Comment: Potentially you don't have [header include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or a [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), and include the header file multiple times in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: You do not show enough context for analysis. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: This [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/D33Aab) fine

Answer (score -3):

I used a simpler approach (avoid doing multiple steps in a single line with ths structs) and had no problem with the following files:

my_entity.h

```
struct EntityStruct {
    long _id;
    char *_myEntityType;
    char *_myEntitySubType;
    long _myEntityGUID;
    long _myEntityOwnerGUID;
    long _myEntityContainerGUID;
} ;

typedef struct EntityStruct MyEntity ;
typedef struct {
    MyEntity *pointer2MyEntity;
} MyContainerEntity;
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_entity.h"

int main()
{
    MyEntity firstEntity;
    MyContainerEntity containerEntity;
    containerEntity.pointer2MyEntity = &firstEntity;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternate content for my_entity.h

```
typedef struct EntityStruct {
   long _id;
   char *_myEntityType;
   char *_myEntitySubType;
   long _myEntityGUID;
   long _myEntityOwnerGUID;
   long _myEntityContainerGUID;
} MyEntity ;

typedef struct {
   MyEntity *pointer2MyEntity;
} MyContainerEntity;
```

OK , I admit I got it wrong, I thought it was necessary to have a separate distinct name for the struct, but even the code that the OP gives works (I did not test it initially, because I went up editing it and tested my version only). So since he does not give full files for the .h and for main(), I guess we cannot help him.

Comment: You haven't explained why the OP's code doesn't work. It should work just as well as yours. Your answer doesn't fix anything, it just shows a slightly different way of doing the same thing.